# How to choose 1 UIImage size for all iPhone resolutions?

Tags: ios, uiimage, screen-resolution

What image size should I choose if I can (at the moment) add only one image size?
Images will be used in `UITableViewCell`, most likely width will be from edge to edge, while height may vary.

So should I add 1242px width images and then app itself would downscale it to 750/640px? Or should I use 750px, because there are more iPhone 6 users than 6+ and more users will have better looking image (in other words more people will see original image, rather than scaled)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 1242px image and downscale it. To get the best possible image quality set `yourUIImageView.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterTrilinear`. You wont see any difference in the image quality when using trilinear filtering.

Another options is to downscale the image before using it:

```
extension UIImage {
  public func rescale(width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    drawInRect(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return scaledImage
  }
}

let myImage = UIImage(named: "myimage").rescale(newWidth, newHeight)
```

Comment: Is it bad, if I simply add image like `cell.myImageView.image = someImage` and that's all? Well, in other words how bad it is?

Comment: If you have set the minificationFilter then you can just set the image to the imageview. Remember to set the correct contentMode to keep the image aspect ratio correct.

Comment: Sooo, I chose Aspect Fit, adjust `UImage.frame.size` to be proportional to original image, then `cell.myImageView.image = someImage` and `cell.myImage.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterTrilinear `

Comment: That's then all you need to do.